# How to export Excel data to SQL server periodically

Tags: sql, excel, export, vba

I have a table in SQL Server for indices, and a spreadsheet which is updated every week for the most recent data. I am looking for an automatic way (VBA? macro? ...?) to export the new data in spreadsheet to the existing table in SQL server to keep the database updated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an SSIS package to import the data. You can also use SQL agent to set a schedule.

You can even get SQL to create the SSIS package for you. If you right click the DB in SSMS and choose tasks -> Import Data. The wizard will walk you through the import and ask if you want it to produce the SSIS package.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can use an excel workbook as a linked server:

http://www.excel-sql-server.com/excel-import-to-sql-server-using-linked-servers.htm

From there you can just write a script to update the table and schedule it.